Nested integrals
I've got an integral which I'm struggling to understand.
Here, $u(x)$ is a function we know (numerically), and $\ell(x)$ is independent of $u$. In case it's relevant, $u$ and $\ell$ are periodic in $[0,L]$, and we can assume $u(0)=0$. In the simple case when $\ell(x)$ is constant what we have is:
$$
\frac{1}{\ell} \int_0^u \int_0^x \frac{d u'}{d x'} dx' \, du' = \frac{1}{\ell} \int_0^u u' \, du' = \frac{1}{\ell} \frac{u^2}{2}.
$$
However, I now need to consider a variable $\ell(x)$ which is inside the integral. I'm a bit lost with what to do:
$$
\int_0^u \int_0^x \frac{1}{\ell(x')}  \frac{d u'}{d x'} dx' \, du'
$$
I've been solving this numerically by finding $\frac{1}{\ell(x)} \times \frac{d u}{d x}$, since $u(x)$ is a function of $x$ and therefore so is $du/dx$. I have then been integrating this numerically over $x$, then doing the outer integral by multiplying by $u$. But when $\ell(x) = 1$ this doesn't give $u^2/2$ because we have "got rid of" the $u$.
The inner integral looks like it has the chain rule applied, but if we integrated $\frac{1}{\ell(x)}$ with respect to $u$, we're losing the result of $\int \frac{1}{\ell(x')} dx'$, aren't we?
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!
Edit:
I think I've narrowed down where my confusion is. When $\ell$ is constant, we unambiguously end up with a function of $u$, i.e. $u^2/2\ell$. When $\ell = \ell(x)$, we could use the numerically-obtained form of $du/dx$, but the inner integral then gives us a function of $x$ and not of $u$. Now that's not a problem, but, I don't understand how we can recover the u^2 term in the case when $\ell(x)=1$. Obviously we can take the $1/\ell$ term out analytically, but I'm solving this integral numerically -- shouldn't there be a method that works regardless of $\ell$?

These integrals make little sense... Can you please fix the variable names? There are way too many $u$'s

Yes, sorry. I think this is partly what is confusing me. I realise the ones inside the integrals should be different variables to the limits so have changed that.

Yes you're right about the derivatives. In the more general case $u$ also depends on time but yes, that doesn't apply here. For arugment's sake we can say u(0)=0 for now too, yes.
